# Objective-C enum is not visible in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have an enum which is like this declared in my objective-c header file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FontSize) {
    VerySmall = 12,
    Small = 14,
    Medium = 16,
    Big = 18
};
```

Then in my bridging header I import this header.

from my swift code, when I try to declare 'FontSize' as parameter, the compiler says 'Use of undeclared type FontSize'.

From the developer guide, this should be possible. Anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `func foo(size : FontSize) { }` compiles for me.

Comment: Works for me, too. Are other things in this interface file visible from Swift? I.e., is it possible that there is a more fundamental bridging header problem? Did you create bridging header yourself, or was it created for you when you added/created Objective-C target and it prompted you to create bridging header automatically?

Comment: I can correctly instantiate the Objective-C class containing the enum but I can't access it. I'm on Xcode 7 beta, ideas?

Comment: It worked fine for me. You'll have to expand your example to show us a reproducible example. Show us [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of an Objective-C class with this enum and how you're trying to use it from Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start over with a clean **Swift** project, add a single `.h` file (accept the automatic creation of Bridging-Headers)

**Objective-C FontSize.h**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FontSize) {
    VerySmall = 12,
    Small = 14,
    Medium = 16,
    Big = 18
};
```

**Bridging-Header**

```
#import "FontSize.h"
```

**Swift Implementation**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let fontSize:FontSize = .VerySmall
}
```

---

*Built, linked, ran & tested on Xcode 6.4 & 7.0.*

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and resolved it by doing BOTH of the following:

1. Move the enum declaration to outside the @interface block
2. Remove the period '.' from the enum reference in the Swift code

`let fontSize:FontSize = VerySmall`

Comment: "Remove the period '.' from the enum reference in the Swift code" helped.

Answer (score 1):

I still couldn't see my enums even with NS_ENUM answer above.

It turns out there was a change in XCode 7.3 where NS_ENUMs have to be defined outside the @interface-@end block.

[Calling obj-c enum from swift not working after upgrading to Xcode 7.3 swift 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195994/calling-obj-c-enum-from-swift-not-working-after-upgrading-to-xcode-7-3-swift-2-2)