# Calling obj-c enum from swift not working after upgrading to Xcode 7.3 swift 2.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, enums, typedef

The code was working well before the upgrade to Xcode 7.3 from 7.1 and swift 2.2. I have also seen answers using the typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyStatus)... but if possible, **I prefer not to change the existing obj-c code**.

Defined in obj-c header file:

```
typedef enum {
    StatusPending,
    StatusTimeout,
    StatusSuccess,
    StatusFail
} MyStatus;
```

Statement in Swift file:

```
/* some code to retrieve the status */

switch (status) {

case .StatusSuccess:
 /* do something */

/* other test cases omitted here */

default:

}
```

I've tried using .rawValue, .value, etc, but I still get an error:

Enum case 'StatusSuccess' not found in type 'MyStatus'

All was working fine before the upgrade and have tried uninstalling/reinstalling Xcode 7.3, Product->Clean, Product->Clean Build Folder.. but without success :-(

Comment: Can you add the answer you got ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't declare "typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger, EnumName){}" within @interface and @end, the parsing of xcode 7.2 is different from xcode 7.3. So, just move your enum declarations outside @interface @end block and it should work fine, otherwise its considered a private declaration

Comment: THANK YOU! That was driving me crazy

Comment: @spfursich yah, I spent quite some time figuring that out too :)

Comment: Well this is silly isn't it? If the enum is declared inside the header file it should be available to all classes that import the file. Now I have it available everywhere!

Comment: That saved my bacon!  It was driving me crazy why I couldn't see my enums.